# Is Grönwall's Lemma true only for non-negative functions?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, continuity

For instance, in this article of [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) a statement is made for Differential form of the Grönwall's Lema for a $\beta, u:I:=[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous functions and $u$ differentiable in the interior $I^{\circ}$ of $I$. That is, $ u $ and $ \beta $ are not necessarily non-negatives. Where,
$$u'(t) \leq \beta(t)u(t) , \; \forall \;  t \in I^{\circ}\Rightarrow u(t) \leq u(a)e^{\int_{a}^{t}\beta(s)}ds, \; \forall \; t \in I.$$

The versions of the Grönwall's Lema that I know of require that the functions be non-negative. Is that what's on Wikipedia right? If so, is there a reference that contains this result?

In the statement of the article, quoted above, an observation is made: *There are no assumptions on the signs of the functions $\beta$ and $u$.*

I did not see error in the proof presented there.